# DB2 StoredProcedure not valid

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

what I missed here, why it is not valide in the context?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST" ()
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL220908110735859
BEGIN
 declare c1 cursor for select * from xyzschema.table;
  DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE abc LIKE xyzschema.table;
  open c1;
  fetch c1 into abc; 
END
```

Error:
{0:0} "abc" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.25.1301

**The main task is to copy content via the stored procedure.**
[Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwHoq.png)

The red rows are already existing. The green rows should be created after the copy. This means the content of the row with id *1* should be copied.
Input parameter is the org_id (here *1*) and tocopy_id (here *2*) from *Table_A* and the condition is that the type should be *A*.

My solution looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
(IN org_id INT, IN tocopy_id INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL220909154402272
BEGIN
--copy contents of Table_B
   FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR 
      select * from TABLE_B where Table_A_Ref = org_id JOIN TABLE_A table_a On Table_A_Ref = table_a.id Where table_a.type = 'A'
   DO 
   --Pk is auto generated
   INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES (tocopy_id, v.name_1, v.name_2);
   END FOR; 
   
   --copy contents of Table_C
END
```

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  Did you read the appropriate manuals for your platform and version?  That's not how you use a temporary table, or a cursor with FETCH INTO.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it as is.

Use of DGTT to store the result of SELECT.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
BEGIN
  DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.ABC AS 
  (
    SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA
  ) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
  -- Do something useful with SESSION.ABC here if needed
END@

CALL TEST@

SELECT * FROM SESSION.ABC@
```

Fetching into a row variable.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
  DECLARE TYPE T_SCHEMATA AS ROW ANCHOR ROW SYSCAT.SCHEMATA;
  DECLARE L_VAR T_SCHEMATA;
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR (5);
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA;
  OPEN C1;
  
  L1:
  LOOP
     FETCH C1 INTO L_VAR;
     IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
     -- Do something useful with L_VAR here
     CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (L_VAR.SCHEMANAME);
  END LOOP L1;
  CLOSE C1;
END@

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF@
```

Comment: Yes it's working now.
But what I do not understand is why this is needed 
`DECLARE abc VARCHAR (128)`
because "abc" was reused afterwards for declaring temp table?

Comment: You can't [FETCH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-fetch) into a table in Db2. You can fetch into a row variable or into a number of "simple" variables. This is why your Declared Global Temporary Table is not used here, and Db2 wants you to declare a variable instead. There can be multiple different techniques depending on what you need to do. See an updated answer.

Comment: Ok thx for the detailed explanation.
My plan is to copy rows for some input parameters.
I have Table A, Table B, ... (Table B is referencing Table_A)
So I want to copy the resultset of this selection below:
`Select * From Table_A
 join Table_B .. 
where input_par and input_par...` 
So when the resultset are two rows, these rows should be copied with other pk into Table A and Table B.
Do you have a suggestion which way should I use or an example?

Comment: Too vague description. Please, provide some complete reproducible example (edit your question for that) including CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO for each of the participating tables, and the result desired (like what should be inserted into what table under what conditions). It would be a long story of coding otherwise...

Comment: I just updated the question above.

Comment: So, what does prevent you from implementing this algorithm? Show your code with the description of a problem or error.

Comment: I add my solution, but I do not know if it is the preferred and fastest way to solve it.

Comment: You don't need any loops for that. Just 1 `INSERT SELECT` statement for each target table like: `INSERT INTO TABLE_B (TABLE_A_REF, NAME_1, NAME_2) 
SELECT tocopy_id, B.NAME_1, B.NAME_2 
FROM TABLE_B B  
JOIN TABLE_A A On A.id = B.Table_A_Ref 
WHERE A.type = 'A' AND B.Table_A_Ref = org_id`

Comment: Yeah right :), is any triggers are activated when inserting in table_b. It should not be activated and no logs should be created during inserting.

Comment: Sure, any valid [BEFORE | AFTER] INSERT trigger is activated on the corresponding INSERT.

Comment: Is it possible to deactivate all triggers inside the stored Procedere?

Comment: You can't disable triggers in Db2 for LUW. You may drop and recreate them inside the routine, if you have the corresponding privilege.